# Tabs doesn't take full width of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

I am creating tabs inside the fragment class. Right now i am showing two tabs in the fragment class. Everything works fine and tabs are shown properly. Only cache is that, the tabs shown only take half of the screen width, It doesn't take the full screen width.

So anyone tell me what i need to change in my code to achieve that

**My Code**

**tabsinfo_fragment.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EFEFEF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

**tab.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"  
    android:background="@drawable/tab_selector">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**code inside fragment class**

```
public class TabsInfoFragment extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener
{
    private View        m_Root;

    private TabHost     m_TabHost;

    private int         m_CurrentTab;

    public  String      m_VisitorTabText;

    public  String      m_FeedTabText;

    public TabsInfoFragment() 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        m_VisitorTabText = Integer.toString(R.string.tab_visitor_text);
        m_FeedTabText = Integer.toString(R.string.tab_feed_text);

        m_Root  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabsinfo_fragment, null);
        m_TabHost = (TabHost) m_Root.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);        
        setupTabs();

        return m_Root;  
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        m_TabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        m_TabHost.setCurrentTab(m_CurrentTab);

        // Manually start loading stuff in the first tab
        updateTab(m_VisitorTabText, R.id.tab_1, new ProfileInfoFragment());
    }

    private void setupTabs() 
    {
        m_TabHost.setup(); 
        m_TabHost.addTab(newTab(m_VisitorTabText, R.string.tab_visitor_text, R.id.tab_1));
        m_TabHost.addTab(newTab(m_FeedTabText, R.string.tab_feed_text, R.id.tab_2));
    }

    private TabSpec newTab(String tag, int labelId, int tabContentId) 
    {       
        View indicator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab, (ViewGroup) m_Root.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs), false);
        ((TextView) indicator.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(labelId);

        TabSpec tabSpec = m_TabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(indicator);
        tabSpec.setContent(tabContentId);
        return tabSpec;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
    {
        if (m_VisitorTabText.equals(tabId)) 
        {
            updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_1, new ProfileInfoFragment());
            m_CurrentTab = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (m_FeedTabText.equals(tabId)) 
        {
            updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_2, new ProfileInfoFragment());
            m_CurrentTab = 1;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void updateTab(String tabId, int placeholder, Fragment fragmentClass) 
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null) 
        {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(placeholder, fragmentClass, tabId).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: if u have only two tabs then remove horizontal scroll view

Comment: @vsk I removed that horizontal scroll view..but it doesn't solve my problem...?

Answer (score 11):

The TabWidget class is a subclass of LinearLayout, so in the tab.xml file for the root xml element, in your case a LinearLayout, set the width to 0dp and the weight to 1, then all the tabs will be equal width.  Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="This is a tab" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: A Real Concept A Real Help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `TabWidget` to this instead;

```
      <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: @Rahul - not really, but one other idea would be to change the `layout_width` in your `tab.xml` file to fill parent

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/tab_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/tab_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Where i put this two <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: instead of tabcontent and realtabcontent change the id of framelayout   as tab_1 and tab_2 , try this and tell me

Comment: Whenever i change name to tab1 in place of @android:id/tabcontent it shows error...saying No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/tab1')

Comment: Now while running got crash..this is my logcat for crash report http://pastebin.com/UQMgwh46

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `HorizontalScrollView` and adding `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `TabWidget`

Answer (score 0):

Need to add one single line

```
tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
```